# Excel: Dynamic range within certain rows + data validation update

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, array-formulas, excel-2016

What I have here is small part of my big data set, with lot of drop downs and functions that are calculating everything around. I am just exceeding this table and trying to make it more automatically than it was before, but I stuck on that part that I put in green.

Which function might be suitable when I wanna add some new cells on the right (right table) named **Model Options** > instead of **Reserviert** but some another name (will be populated later), but to automatically recognize it on left drop down reference cell (**Model**)?
I will have some additional workbook which is gonna be updated frequently, and from that workbook I have to lookup everything what is "new" and to populate it here in certain order like in this two small examples..

Up till now I managed to find OFFSET and INDEX functions:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1;1;0;COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B)-1;2) or `=$A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))`
```

..but it didnt work. My Data set (Columns T and U) are not starting from the top rows, but somewhere in the middle (other data is before and after it), and that gives me trouble especially when I am including new rows...

Hopefully I was clear with question.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you dont have to use full column ranges.

For the first list you just have to add a `COUNTBLANK` in the `OFFSET`, so that list skips the blank cells. This won't work for blank cells in between the data entries.

```
=OFFSET(T14:T18,COUNTBLANK(T14:T18),,COUNTA(T14:T18))
```

As for the second list you can use

```
=OFFSET(Tabelle1!T20:T26,,,COUNTA(Tabelle1!U20:U26))
```

Here I used the code column to count the number of entries. You can shift it over to the endpoint column by modifying the ranges in the `COUNTA`-function. This is just to show of some further possibilities.

[image]

Hopefully i was clear with my answer. :) If i didn't hit the spot, let me know.

Comment: Thx for this suggest! But I got the same issue actually, when I trying to ADD additional row at the end of first or second list...it isn't automatically updated! 

That was my biggest problem actually..  :/

Comment: You can leave the last row as a dummy row and add new rows just before it to make the predefined ranges expand as needed.

Comment: Hmm yeah it seems to work like this, just small correction in the first list where you wrote in COUNTA (Column T, instead of U) 

`=OFFSET(T14:T18,COUNTBLANK(T14:T18),,COUNTA(U14:U18))`

If one of this columns are not filled/defined, you wont have "empty blank field" in Data Validation option. I tried it on more ways, and referencing exactly like this is fine. 
Luckily in my case, this field (dummy one) will always persist as a last position for an internal overview, so I can use your suggest. 

I would close this support, considering it fine! 

Thanks @OverflowStacker