# Excel Help: Dynamic range + Data Validation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I got a problem with some popular Excel question, dynamic ranges and data validation drop-downs and auto-populate. Lets say I got 2 sheets, and on one sheet I got drop-downs to choose from another sheet, and that is not a problem when I define cells and range using:

[image]

```
=OFFSET($A$19;;;COUNTA('0528 - info'!$E$2))
```

..but what about when I wanna add some new cells in between,so that they can be automatically recognized in which group they belong:

As you see for instance Column B has some "groups" where you can find more different "values" like in Column C, like Power Supply has MV1 and MV2... and so on. My drop-downs on the sheet 1 are called exactly like this "groups" and I did reference them manually using given function. But is it possible to populate my drop-downs automatically when I add for instance MV3 beneath MV2 in this table? Or RN7 on 14th row? Everytime I add new values I have to extend my dropdowns (what is fine..), but problem will be when I share this table to others, they gonna forget it 90%.

[image]
I hope you get my point, any suggest will be fine!

p.s. Indirect doesnt work in a way it should - It gives me all instances from the Column but not specific ones that I need.

```
=INDIRECT("Table4[VarEDS]")
```

Well this option gave me again what I already had before - all "matches" from the Column and still not ONLY matches that are for certain group. ...

[image]

Comment: Can you explain further (or upload a picture of) the dropdowns? I'm not sure I understand what you want to appear in them, and what the issue actually is.

Comment: Voting to close as `Needing more details or clarity`.  In its current state, this post is both difficult to read and to understand intention, so answering would be speculative at best.  Please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60549256/edit) to be more clear.

Comment: @RogB

Okay, I will edit it precisely (hopefully). Gimme a minute.

Comment: @Cyril Okay, I will edit it precisely (hopefully). Gimme a minute.

Comment: @RogB  Edited!! You can have a look!

Comment: @Cyril I did editing! Every help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some days of searching and trying I got what I wanted - wasnt wasy job at all. Needed to combine more functions with the help of couple of videos from Leyla (Xelplus):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gu4xJWAIal8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fYlWeMQ6L8&t=5s

First step was to make unique list of my values (text in my case) on separate sheet:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(t_VarGroup[Vargrouptext];MATCH(0;INDEX(COUNTIF($J$2:J2;t_VarGroup[Vargrouptext]););0));"")
```

Then I needed to "extract" all the values that are belonging to the certain unique values:

```
=@IF($I3<COLUMNS($K$2:K$2);"";INDEX(t_EDS[[VarEDS]:[VarEDS]];AGGREGATE(15;3;(t_VarGroup[[Vargrouptext]:[Vargrouptext]]=$J3)/(t_VarGroup[[Vargrouptext]:[Vargrouptext]]=$J3)*(ROW(t_VarGroup[Vargrouptext])-ROW(t_VarGroup[[#Headers];[Vargrouptext]]));COLUMNS($K$2:K$2))))
```

FUrthermore, I created Unique drop down list:

```
=OFFSET($J$3;;;COUNTIF($J$3:$J$14;"?*"))
```

And then dependent drop down list nearby using:

```
=OFFSET($K$2;MATCH($H$2;$J$3:$J$17;0);;1;COUNTIF(OFFSET($K$2;MATCH($H$2;$J$3:$J$17;0);;1;20);"?*"))
```

And because I made it on other sheet, I had to reference them to an appropriate sheet name where my main sheet is - with drop downs, it is actually very useful for my future work and for everyone else who has struggling with drop downs but on a bit specific way =))

credits to: @Naresh Bhople  for suggestion about Youtube videos.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If your Data Validation source is a "Table" as shown in your image then you can take advantage of "Table Column" Range which is dynamic. That means whenever you refer that column as NAMED range and if make changes to the column (Edit, Add, Delete) it will reflect in the referred cell.

You can use this technique even for ranges not in table. You need to NAME them with offset formula and make dynamic.

You can find dynamic address of your column as shown in the image below. Select entire column WITHOUT Header

[image]

Name your column data range with appropriate name as shown in image below

[image]

Then in Data Validation Window refer this name using F3 as shown in image below.

[image]

Then you can see... Even if you edit, add or delete any row in the column the data validation will change

[image]

[image]

Editing based on your comment below: If you want text from column B and Column C appear together in the validation dropdown list. Insert column in the table and join text from column B and C and then make data validation based on that column as shown in Colum D in image below

[image]

Finally I think I understood your question.
Watch this video
[Excel: Find Multiple Matches & Dependent Drop Down List](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gu4xJWAIal8)

Comment: You had this question repetitively .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013264/excel-dynamic-range-within-certain-rows-data-validation-update...

Comment: Thanks man but still didnt work - I had the same results even before. I edited my post again. 

I knew I asked before, I got bored to use manually that is reason I asked on different way with better screen shots.

Comment: It was really hard to understand your question.  :).. But I think I have understood it now. So you want to autoupdate data validation in First Sheet1 which is based on column B of second sheet2 when you change value in Column C of Sheet2 .. Am I right?

Comment: Data Validation list source must be a column or a row. It cannot be a table. So, insert a column in your table. Concatenate all the cells in the rows in that column. And the make validation in Sheet1 based on that column...

Comment: Wait, you mean completely new column with concatinating Column B and C from Sheet 2?

Comment: Hah..actually it is not what I asked. look...Important is main sheet with drop downs, as you can see all of them got names that are exactly as they are in database sheet (like in Column B: Model, Power Supply and so on..) and beneath is my drop down that should populate all the values that correspond to the given part (model, power supply, gas sensor...) and you can see then in Column C, in short for written.

Comment: So imagine that I am getting like MV1, MV2... MV10.. all of them will be in database sheet but not in a drop downs for the certain group because I cant figure properly function and populating of certain groups.

Hard to explain.

Comment: Answer edited .. see last line of the answer.. Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gu4xJWAIal8