# Nested ifs in Data Validation in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two dropdowns in spreadsheet. When user choose `U` in first dropdown there is `=IF(prefix="U",Uoption,"-")` then in second dropdown there are only values from `Uoption` but now when I try to add second option: `=IF(prefix="U",Uoption,"-"),=IF(prefix="D","WKN","-")` I get an error: `The formula you typed contains an error`. I also tried:`=IF(prefix="U",Uoption,=IF(prefix="D","WKN","-"))` but got the same error. How to correctly use nested if in `Data Validation`?

@Edit

In cell C3 there is dropdown with two elements (`source: U, D`)
In cell C4 there is another dropdown which should work this way: if 'U'-> Uoption, else if 'D' -> 'WKN'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549256/excel-help-dynamic-range-data-validation/60552348#60552348  ......and ......   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gu4xJWAIal8

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`=IF(prefix="US",Uoption,IF(prefix="D","WKN","-"))`

Comment: `The list source must be a delimited list, or a reference to single row or column.` ;/

Comment: Try to put a sample of your data for better understanding