# Ms Excel: Dependent Dropdown only works for first row

Tags: excel

I have gone through below tutorials

https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/

https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html

I have created Names.

I am able to create Dependent drop down list. But some how it is only for 1st row only

Although I copy/paste 1st row to 2nd row.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549256/excel-help-dynamic-range-data-validation

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best approach is to create an Excel table and indirect the table columns.

**Example:**

- Create a table and name it *tblNames*
- Select the cell where the data validation should be
- Select Data tab- Data tools - Data Validation - On *Allow* drop down select `List` - On *Source* write `=INDIRECT("tblNames[Names]")`

[image]

This import a data validation refer to table name - column name

**Results**

[image]